# How to print Rack::Request as raw HTTP request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

I interested in the `standard` way to print an instance of a `Rack::Request` class as a text HTTP request. Example below.

```
POST /cgi-bin/process.cgi HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE5.01; Windows NT)
Host: www.tutorialspoint.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://clearforest.com/">string</string>
```

It would be nice for debugging and share with users. I have a team with non-rails stack using my API and raw requests will be useful.

Comment: I believe you would need to emulate this option. The original request doesn't get passed along by the server - only the parsed result.

Comment: You would need to wrap `env` into a rack request object and then pretty print it: `request = Rack::Request.new(env)`